# Passing a vb variable to an SQL statement in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I've tried hard to make sure I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, so apologies if it's a repeat.

I want to use a WHERE clause to filter data output from an SQL Server statement to items which are less than two weeks old. I've successfully managed to write the .vb code to get the date from two weeks ago, however I'm having trouble trying to insert this date into the statement from my .aspx page.

The code to calculate the date two weeks ago is as follows:

```
Protected dateBuffer As String = lastFortnight().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Function lastFortnight() As DateTime       
    Dim retVal As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)
    Return retVal
End Function
```

This returns a date of 06/01/2014 (as of today) if called on my .aspx page using <%=dateBuffer %>

However if I try and insert it into my SQL statement to filter the outputs like so:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database SQL 20130905ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database SQL 20130905ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT [ReqNumber], [ApprovedDate], [Approved] FROM [RequisitionDetails] WHERE ([RequestDate] &gt;= ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue='<%=dateBuffer %>' Name="RequestDate" Type="DateTime" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I consistently get the error

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I've spent most of my day searching for how to fix this, and I'm still no closer than I was 4 hours ago. If I'm making any stupid mistakes please let me know... I'm a complete newbie when it comes to any of this stuff, It's the first time I've ever worked with .aspx, .vb and SQL server.

Comment: I don't know if VB works different, but in C# if I initialize a field that initialization only works at app startup and doesn't create a link between the field and the method - If you leave it running for a day that date is now 15 days in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL's date format differs from the .NET DateTime data type, which is why you're getting the formatting error. There are ways to convert, such as using the SqlDateTime struct - [How can I convert a .Net Datetime to a T-SQL Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822000/how-can-i-convert-a-net-datetime-to-a-t-sql-datetime)

In your case though, might it not be simpler to pass the number of days to your SQL statement (or stored proc), and use a DateDiff/DateAdd combination in SQL ?